# how to retain colour when you import .stl file into blender

Tags: import

I had a .spk file, then exported it into blender as a .stl file. but when I imported it into blender and went into rendered mode there was no colour. there was no colour in material preview mode as well.

Comment: Seems stl file format doesn't support colors by default, only in its binary version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)

Comment: is there like an add-on for this maybe?